# Recycler view does not appear when parent view is converted to a bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin

I am attempting to convert a view constraint layout containing a recycler view into a bitmap to use as a wallpaper. The contents of the recycler view displays in app but the bitmap will either throw an error when i try to create it or be completly white depending on what i try, any advice?

main_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/taskRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
val viewModel:TaskViewModle = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TaskViewModle::class.java)
        //get target view
        val viewContent:View = findViewById(R.id.includedView)
        val wallBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.wallBTN)
        val wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
        
        //on click set wallpaper
        wallBtn.setOnClickListener {
            viewContent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)
            val bm = getBitmapFromView(viewContent)
            try {
                wm.setBitmap(bm)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("error :(", "Cannot set image as wallpaper", e)
            }
        }

        val quoteAdapter = TaskAdapter(this)
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.taskRecycler)
        recyclerView.adapter = quoteAdapter
        viewModel.readAllTask.observe(this, Observer { task -> quoteAdapter.setData(task)
        })


        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)


    fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap? {
        view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getLayoutParams().width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getLayoutParams().height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth() view.getMeasuredHeight());
        
        val b:Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

        val c:Canvas = Canvas(b);
        view.draw(c)

        return b}
```

This code causes me to get the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

When i try the follwing code

```
 val viewModel:TaskViewModle = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TaskViewModle::class.java)
        val viewContent:View = findViewById(R.id.includedView)

        val wallBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.wallBTN)
        val wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
        wallBtn.setOnClickListener {
            viewContent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)
            val bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewContent.getDrawingCache())
            try {
                wm.setBitmap(bm)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("error :(", "Cannot set image as wallpaper", e)
            }
        }

        val quoteAdapter = TaskAdapter(this)
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.taskRecycler)
        recyclerView.adapter = quoteAdapter



        viewModel.readAllTask.observe(this, Observer { task -> quoteAdapter.setData(task)


        })




        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

The bitmap is plain white

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? I would avoid programmatical bitmap creation, if you need to show unusable recycler, you can just draw it in constraint layout and set its enabled state to false

Comment: The recycler can be added to by the user and i'm wanting to allow the user to set the list of items in the recycler view as a wallpaper, so i need the current content of the recycler view to be saved in the bitmap image